# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded on integrate, sympy 1.1.1

Tags: python, sympy

Bug entered at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/14877

---

Is this a known issue? Is this a new bug? Will report if new.

What could cause it?

```
>which python
/opt/anaconda/bin/python

>pip list | grep sympy
sympy                              1.1.1

>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

from sympy import *
x=symbols('x');
integrate(exp(1-exp(x**2)*x+2*x**2)*(2*x**3+x)/(1-exp(x**2)*x)**2,x)
```

gives

```
.....
 File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/mul.py", line 1067, in <genexpr>
    a.is_commutative for a in self.args)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
>>>
```

btw, the anti derivative should be

```
  -exp(1-exp(x^2)*x)/(-1+exp(x^2)*x)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a known issue that SymPy fails to integrate many functions. This particular function probably wasn't reported yet, so by all means, add it to the [ever-growing list](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues).

SymPy tries several integration approaches. One of them, called "manual integration", is highly recursive: a substitution or integration by parts is attempted, and then the process is repeated for the resulting integral.

In this specific case, the expression has a lot of functions that look like candidates for substitution: `x**2`, the denominator, the content of another exponential function. And SymPy goes into an infinite chain of substitution that leads not to a solution but to a stack overflow... There is no pattern implemented in `integrate` that would tell SymPy to make the crucial substitution `u = 1 - x*exp(x**2)`.

There is a separate, experimental, integrator called RUBI which could be used with

```
from sympy.integrals.rubi.rubi import rubi_integrate
rubi_integrate(exp(1-exp(x**2)*x+2*x**2)*(2*x**3+x)/(1-exp(x**2)*x)**2, x)
```

but it relies on [MatchPy](https://github.com/HPAC/matchpy) which I don't have installed, so I can't tell if it would help here.

Comment: I installed MatchPy now, successfully using `sudo conda install -c conda-forge matchpy`  But there is no such command as rubi_integrate anywhere.  `>>> from sympy.integrals.rubi.rubi import rubi_integrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy.integrals.rubi'` I also did `from sympy import *` and typed your commands and still got an error `rubi_integrate` is not defined.  Are your sure `rubi_integrate` is in sympy 1.1.1 ?  I would try it if I know how to use it `>pip list | grep -i matchpy` gives `matchpy   0.4.4`

Comment: Indeed, it's not in 1.1.1... you can get that module by running the dev version from [Github](https://github.com/sympy/sympy). (It also has fewer bugs than 1.1.1, including in `integrate`, although the issue with the particular function is still there.)